# Where did the word "mafia" appear in Puzo's original screenplay of "The Godfather"?

Tags: cinema-history, the-godfather

The New York Times documents that Joseph Columbo pressured producer Al Ruddy to remove all occurrences of "Mafia" and "Casa Nostra" from the movie "The Godfather".

An article on knowledgenuts.com claims that prior to their meeting, the word "Mafia" only appeared once in the screenplay.  I can't find any corroboration of that claim.

I did some current searches of the screenplay, but can't find a version of the screenplay that contains either phrase.

Where in the original screenplay did those words appear?

Comment: I do not know about the screenplay, but in the book they appear quite often. In fact IIRC the book credits Vito Corleone for coining the `cosa nostra` term in a meeting with other *maffiosi*; more or less he says that their bussines are *cosa nostra* (our thing) and that outsiders (police, etc.) should not interfere.

Comment: Side trivia: The relevant article in the New York Times ( https://archive.nytimes.com/www.nytimes.com/packages/html/movies/bestpictures/godfather-ar1.html?scp ) was written by Nicholas Pileggi, who would later go on to write the screenplays for the Martin Scorsese movies "Casino" and "Goodfellas".

Comment: If i recall, in Godfather Part 2 they use the terms Mafia and Casa Nostra at the senate hearing. but as i said, thats in Part 2, and your question is on Part 1

Comment: When Godfather Part 2 was made, Joseph Columbo was dead, so presumably the same agreements were no longer in effect.

Comment: According to [THR](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/godfather-movie-quotes-rare-look-873073): "Mario Puzo's literary archive — 45 bankers boxes of material, including the original 744-page draft of the the Godfather novel (working title: Mafia), nine partial and eight complete versions of the Godfather script, multiple drafts of the Godfather II and III scripts, letters between Puzo and director Francis Ford Coppola, and hundreds of pages of handwritten notes — sold at auction to a private collector for $625,000 in February 2016." so the question is hard to answer.